# Regex MATCHES only store certain amount to match collection

Tags: c#, regex

How can I just store lets say 100 strings into my match collection istead of all matches I just want the first or random 100.

```
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(homePage.Html.InnerText, @"regex(regex)regex");

Match firstMatch = matches[0];

if (matches[0].Success)
{
    log("[-] Found: " + matches.Count.ToString());
}
```

I want to simply store match only lets say 100 of the few thousand matches.
I dont want to do this after by looping through and adding to list/array I would rather do during the matching process, so my match collection only contains 100.

Answer (score 0):

Provide a subset of the text to search, eg:

```
homePage.Html.InnerText.Substring(0,1000)
```

In your code this would look like this:

```
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(homePage.Html.InnerText.Substring(0,1000), @"regex(regex)regex");
```

Or

> The syntax is {min,max}, where min is a positive integer number
>   indicating the minimum number of matches, and max is an integer equal
>   to or greater than min indicating the maximum number of matches.